# how to hold the state of the checkbox while doing pagination in struts2

Tags: struts2, pagination, displaytag

I am using struts2 to develop an application in that I have done pagination using Display tag
In pagination I have generated one check box per a row(some of them are checked) When user checks  them and paginate to second page and when he come back to first page all are unchecked 
  If you need any code I will provide you 
PLease tell me the way that can solve my issue.

Thanks IN Advance

Comment: When you check the them make sure you save the result somewhere, so it repopulate the values again.

Comment: I am generating those Checkboxes dynamically I mean from DB.. Then How to hold their state and how to retrive them back.. Please be more expressive .. THanks in advance

Comment: Checkboxes like other controls keep the state in the `value` attribute. There's nothing changed in Struts2 that has nothing with the DB, however many appliances use it for their backends.

Comment: Would like to see the code .....

Comment: `<d:table name="doclist" export="false" class="table" pagesize="1000" requestURI="" id="current" > <d:column><s:checkbox value="#{attr.current.check}" fieldVaue="#{attr.current.docno}" /> </d:column><d:table>` This is my JSP code with this I can get checkboxes But I cant retain their status while doing paginaiton.. For this I have seen some links in NET [link](http://demo.displaytag.org/displaytag-examples-1.2/example-checkboxes.jsp) .. BUt this one is not working